# Recognize .NET MAUI Image loading failure

Tags: .net, image, maui

I'm using the .NET MAUI Image control to display images stored on disk.

In rare cases an image file can be damaged, so the image cannot be loaded into the Image control. If this happens, I see an exception in the log:

> Microsoft.Maui.FileImageSourceService: Warning: Unable to load image
> file
> '/Users/frank/Library/c12d2fe8-90bb-4a19-9887-6091059ea74d-2023-02-20T10-44-41-855Z'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load image file.    at
> Microsoft.Maui.FileImageSourceService.GetImageAsync(IFileImageSource
> imageSource, Single scale, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I would like to display a special warning symbol if loading fails.

How can I catch this exception or get to know in any other way, if loading has succeeded or failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use try...catch to catch exceptions to check whether the loading is successful, refer to the following:

```
public TestPageOne()
{
    var image = new Image();
 
    Content = new VerticalStackLayout
    {
       Children = {
                     new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, Text = "Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                   },
                     image
                 }
             };
 
       try
           {
              image.Source = "one.png";
                       
           }catch(Exception ex)
           {
              DisplayAlert("error",ex.Message,"OK");
           }
    
}
```

I noticed that you also raised this question on the Q&A([Recognize .NET MAUI Image loading failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194367/recognize-net-maui-image-loading-failure)). You can also refer to the `GetPlatformImageAsync` method to determine whether the returned result is empty to determine whether the image is loaded successfully. The reference is as follows:

```
<Image x:Name="img"
    Loaded="Image_Loaded"
    Source="dotnet.png"
    ...
    />
private async void Image_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    var res = await img.Source.GetPlatformImageAsync(Handler.MauiContext);
    if (res == null)
    {
        img.Source = "dotnet_bot.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but neither of the two proposed solutions works.

In the first proposal, an exception is never thrown here when the Source is assigned. It is thrown later in the rendering phase, when the system really tries to load the image.

In the second proposal, Handler is unknown (CS0103: The name 'Handler' does not exist in the current context).

To me, the second one seems the most promising, but I don't know how to get a MauiContext at this place.

Comment: Let's pay attention to [the answers in Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194367/recognize-net-maui-image-loading-failure#:~:text=Handler%20is%20an%20internal%20property%20of%20ContentPage%2C%20did%20you%20add%20this%20code%20to%20a%20place%20where%20the%20non%2Dpage%20code%2Dbehind%20code%3F).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the hint in Q&A, the Handler.MauiContext in the second solution can be taken from the ContentPage for example. My problem here was that the image is located inside a DataTemplate for a CollectionView.

I've slightly changed the second solution, because using the Loaded event sometimes didn't work. Instead I've used the property change for IsLoading, which is fired every time the CollectionView cell becomes visible during scrolling.

Besides this, I had to catch the exception instead of checking res to be null.

So this is my working code now:

```
image.PropertyChanged += async (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs eargs) => {

    if (eargs.PropertyName == "IsLoading") {

        if (!image.IsLoading) {

            var mauiContext = /* get ContentPage.Handler.MauiContext */;

            try {

                var res = await image.Source.GetPlatformImageAsync(mauiContext);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                Debug.WriteLine($"EXCEPTION CAUGHT {e}");

                image.Source = "error.png";
            }
        }
    }
};
```